# Multiple WHERE, LIKE conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, where-clause, sql-like

Is this query valid? Or do I need to break it down more?

```
SELECT SUM(colA) as 'colA',
       SUM(colB) as 'colB'
FROM tblName 
WHERE colA,colB REGEXP 'Fail'
OR colA, colB='Pass'
ORDER BY colA, colB;
```

Reason I ask is I have a large amount of columns to look up and I am trying to discover the most effective way of doing this without writing this long drawn out query.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you have to write it out; though the query you've presented makes very little sense in general.

Comment: You didn't describe what you are having issues with.. There also is no `like` in this question.

Comment: I added like just in case someone suggests something involving like. I also am not currently having issue. I was investigating my potential ways to approach this and decided to ask before wasting too much time. THough I got my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `=`/equality testing, there's the `IN` notation:

```
WHERE x=1 or x=2 or x=3 ....
WHERE x='pass' or y='pass' or ....
```

can be a simple

```
WHERE x IN (1,2,3,....)
WHERE 'pass' IN (x,y,....)
```

You MAY be able to do something similar with regex matches, e.g.

```
WHERE 'Fail' REGEXP CONCAT(colA, colB, etc...)
```

but that depends on exactly what your regex pattern is. For anything else, there's no shortcuts. You have to write it all out.

Comment: I was afraid that i'd have to write it all out. Thanks